# Jags in r statistics: What is the appropriate structure of data for estimating parameters in an equation system with > 1000 variables?

Tags: r, statistics, bayesian, jags

I got some equation system looking like:

y = t1*x1+ t2*x2 + t3*x3 ....

Where x is the count of some activities, x1 = activtiy1, x2 = activity2 and so on... y ist the overall time needed for all those activities.

I got a table with the columns: y, x1, x2, x3, [...] and one line for each data entry. So each line of my table is one equation. My goal is to calculate a propability range for the time t1, t2, ... and so on which is needed to acomplish the activities.

I succeed with generating a jags model (using package runjags in r statistics / r studio) and got some results. Therefore i grouped the activities, so i only got 10 categories of activities which i summed up, that my code gets shorter.

In the model the code actualy looks like:

```
time.z[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], 1/sigma[organizationalunit.int[i]]^2)

mu[i] <- c.organizationalunit[organizationalunit.int[i]] +
       beta.x1 * x1[i] +
       beta.x2 * x2[i] +
       beta.x3 * x3[i] +
       beta.x4 * x4[i] +
       [...]
```

Now i want to calculate it for each activitie and not for groups of activities. This would raise the column count (and variable count in the equation) from about 10-15 to 1000-1500. I don't think that it is appropriate to write a model like in the example above for >1000 variables in the equation.

The problem is, y is always the result of a whole line. If i change the structure of the table i am working with to columns like: y, activity identifier, activty count

That would make the model much shorter BUT: i only got a y value for a whole line like shown in the first example. How to deal with this problem? I would be very thankful for any advice! Even recommendations for other programming languages or methods for the calculation are welcome.

Thank you!